# How to create a dynamic horizontal rule based on an int value using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create something like the image in an MVC project.

When I get the flight duration from the Model,

I want to show lines depicting the duration but I can't seem to understand how to do this dynamically.
[Flight Duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccvTU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div element with height: 3px and background-color: black and and set its width to the int value.

CSS:

```
.duration-line{
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').append('<div class="duration-line" style="width: ' + duration + 'px"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks I guess i could use that. But the duration will be like 6 hours or 3 hours or something like. I cant have a line for 3px. So I need to take the whole box as fixed width 100% and then split according to that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its just mathematics.

Lets assume:
- space for the lines is 200px wide
- you have 2 legs in the journey, one 6 hrs and one 12 hrs

Set leg 1 width to (6 / (6+12)) * 200 = 66.6px
Set leg 2 width to (12 / (6+12)) * 200 = 133.3px

Comment: There a number of ways you can do it... you just need to apply some kind of mathematical factor to the durations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a input type range

```
$('#container').append('<input type="range" disabled id="myRange" min="0" max="6" value="3">');
```

Comment: yes it will, you will need to set a max and a value and to style it how you want it to look like

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was not clear. An input type range will need a maximum width which does not change and a slider which is controlled by "value". I'm looking for a way to set the maximum width dynamically similar to the range control.

Comment: you mean something like this ? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Answer (score 0):

i think you can simply do this way

```
.duration-line{
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: @(Model.Duration)px;
}
```